# Is it possible to convert external tables to native in BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery

I have created a table from Google Cloud Storage (filepath starts with gs://). I could not create it as native even after trying multiple times. I succeeded only after setting the table option as native. Later, I was able to query this table successfully. However, I need to do the following:

1. Add a column to the table
2. Append (union) two such external tables
3. Join the appended table with another external table
4. save the joined table in a new table so that I can later query this new table

**Questions:**
Since this is an external table, can I add a column? Can I save the joined table as native?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can convert an external table (or federated source) to a native table in BigQuery.

To do this, simply read the external table using SQL and set the destination table for the results. BigQuery will then write the results of your query to a native table.

[image]

Comment: It is now under "Save Results" where you can choose BigQuery table as a format.