# BigQuery : "Encountered an error while globbing file pattern" using a view of a table of a drive file

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-drive-api, google-cloud-iam

I have this view :
[image]

---

It uses a table (`....prod_server_api.mongo_episode_history`) that was created importing a csv file from a drive :

[image]

---

Every time I request this view from **ie a nodeJS local script**, it fails with this error :

```
'SELECT * FROM [myCompany]-bigquery.prod_data_studio.episodes_listened LIMIT 10'
```

These errors :

```
(node:26572) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Access Denied: BigQuery BigQuery: Permission denied while globbing file pattern.
at new ApiError (D:\Coding\[myCompany]\[myCompany]\node_modules\@google-cloud\bigquery\node_modules\@google-cloud\common\build\src\util.js:73:15)
at Util.parseHttpRespBody (D:\Coding\[myCompany]\[myCompany]\node_modules\@google-cloud\bigquery\node_modules\@google-cloud\common\build\src\util.js:208:38)
at Util.handleResp (D:\Coding\[myCompany]\[myCompany]\node_modules\@google-cloud\bigquery\node_modules\@google-cloud\common\build\src\util.js:149:117)
at D:\Coding\[myCompany]\[myCompany]\node_modules\@google-cloud\bigquery\node_modules\@google-cloud\common\build\src\util.js:479:22
at onResponse (D:\Coding\[myCompany]\[myCompany]\node_modules\@google-cloud\bigquery\node_modules\retry-request\index.js:228:7)
at D:\Coding\[myCompany]\[myCompany]\node_modules\@google-cloud\bigquery\node_modules\teeny-request\src\index.ts:333:11
at propagateAslWrapper (D:\Coding\[myCompany]\[myCompany]\node_modules\async-listener\index.js:504:23)
```

### A few additional data :

1. I can query all other "regular" tables **in the same piece of script**. I'm using a JSON credentials key for a service account, that works perfectly well all around my codebase.
2. My service account has access to the source document (a drive CSV) : [image]
3. My service account has of course access to the tables, and also the table has the access to its source table.

I followed these :

- ["Encountered an error while globbing file pattern" error when using BigQuery API w/ Google Sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40731823/encountered-an-error-while-globbing-file-pattern-error-when-using-bigquery-api) but I can't seem to understand step 2 (and I don't think I should be concerned by it).
- [Query table in Google BigQuery has error "Access Denied: BigQuery BigQuery: Permission denied while globbing file pattern."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64276972/query-table-in-google-bigquery-has-error-access-denied-bigquery-bigquery-perm) (i'm not reading from a bucket)
- [BigQuery: Permission denied while globbing file pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41689465/bigquery-permission-denied-while-globbing-file-pattern) (which goes back to 1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't solve this, I got round it by copying the table using external data to a native table using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43386615/is-it-possible-to-convert-external-tables-to-native-in-bigquery).

Data is now disconnected from external (I know) but at least I can go on :)